# struct string variable assignment in C

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    double gpa;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Student s1;
    s1.age = 20;
    s1.gpa = 4.3;
    s1.name[10] = "Tom";

    printf("%s", s1.name);

    return 0;
}
```

I know 'strcpy' function or other way to assign string. but Why doesn't it work above code..?
Please help me.

Specially, s1.name[10] = "Tom";

Thanks.

Comment: `s1.name` has only 10 elements starting from `s1.name[0]`, so `s1.name[10]` is out-of-range and you must not access (no read nor write) there.

Comment: The syntax you're using only works for an initializer. For example, `char name[10] = "Tom";` works because it declares and initializes the array. But `char name[10]; name = "Tom";` won't work because arrays cannot be assigned.

Comment: @JWJ FWIW, `s1.name = "Tom";` might make some sense in a future rev of C, but not today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with this statement:

```
s1.name[10] = "Tom";
```

In C array (of length `n`) indexing starts with `0` and ends at `n-1`. Accessing any elements out side of `0` to `n-1` (both inclusive) will cause undefined behaviour. `s1.name[10]` is out of bound access and not valid.

Another problem is that you cannot assign a string literal to an array using assignment operator except when it is used in the initializer. You have to use `strcpy` to copy a string literal to a `char` array. Make sure length of string literal must not exceed the size of the array (make sure there is a room for `\0`).

Answer (score 0):

In this expression statement

```
s1.name[10] = "Tom";
```

the left side operand has the type `char`. Moreover in this expression s1.name[10] there is dereferenced pointer that points outside the allocated array.

The right side operand after the implicit conversion has the type `char *`.

So you are trying to assign a pointer to a non-existent element of the array.

Pay attention to that arrays do not have the assignment operator.

You could initialize the object of the structure type when it is defined like

```
 struct Student s1=
 {
    .name = "Tom",
    .age = 20,
    .gpa = 4.3
};
```